# Changing HTML code with Javascript . not quite working

Tags: javascript, html

I have a fairly long form on a page with various checkboxes and text boxes. There is one point where I want a text box to become available if a corresponding checkbox is ticked. I almost have it working with this code:

```
<tr class= "formspace">
<td class="formleft" valign="top" style="line-height:22px">Extra bed(s)?</td>
<td colspan="2"><input name="extrabed" type="checkbox" value="1" onChange="jsextrabed()"><?php echo $lang["extraadultx"]." ".$lang["notsingleoccx"];?>   
<div id="extrabednumber"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function jsextrabed() {
if(document.roomnew.extrabed.checked == 1) {
document.getElementById("extrabednumber").innerHTML='&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Max number of extra beds <input name="extrabed" type="text" id="extrabed" size="1" maxlength="1" value="1">';
}else{
document.getElementById("extrabednumber").innerHTML='&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Max number of extra beds <input name="extrabed" type="text" id="extrabed" size="1" maxlength="1" value="0">';
}
}
</script>
</td>
</tr>
```

When the page first opens, only the checkbox shows.

When I tick the checkbox, the text box opens with a value of 1. So far, so good.

When I click again the checkbox is unticked and the value in the text box changes to 0. Still good.

When I click yet again the checkbox is ticked (good) but the value in the text box stays at 0 (bad!).

Further clicking toggles the checkbox but has no effect on the value in the text box.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: what is `document.roomnew`? I guess some `<form>`, but it will be nice if you put all your code

Comment: Is that really the requirement, though?  What's the expected behavior if the user keeps the checkbox unchecked and adds a non-zero number to the text box?  Wouldn't it be better to hide the text box whenever it is not required?

Answer (score 0):

use this code for check:

```
if(document.roomnew.extrabed.checked) {
```

Comment: `TRUE` (in all-caps) is not a JS keyword.  And even `true` is probably not best.  Just test the variable directly to see if it's truthy, e.g. `if (document.roomnew.extrabed.checked) {...}`

Comment: Mohammed and Scott, I take your point about just using "checked" with no "== true" or anything of the sort. Unfortunately the problem still persists.
I tried replacing the content of innerHtml with "Checked" and "Not checked" and that works perfectly, so it seems that there is something in the code inside the innerHtml that is causing the problem. The search continues ......

Answer (score 0):

Just check with

```
if(document.roomnew.extrabed.checked){
}
else
{ 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in the displayed code.

Here's a working demonstration : http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/u6mtW/

**HTML :**

```
<tr class= "formspace">
<td class="formleft" valign="top" style="line-height:22px">Extra bed(s)?</td>
<td colspan="2"><input name="extrabed" id=checkextra type="checkbox" value="1" >some php   
<div id="extrabednumber"></div>
</td>
</tr>​
```

**Javascript :**

```
<script>
    window.onload=function(){
        document.getElementById('checkextra').onchange = function() {
            if(this.checked) {
                 document.getElementById("extrabednumber").innerHTML='&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Max number of extra beds <input name="extrabed" type="text" id="extrabed" size="1" maxlength="1" value="1">'; 
            }else{
                 document.getElementById("extrabednumber").innerHTML='&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Max number of extra beds <input name="extrabed" type="text" id="extrabed" size="1" maxlength="1" value="0">';
            }
        }​;
    };
</script>
```

I made a few changes to

- adapt to the fact that we don't have the whole DOM. Your problem may be there, in the parts we don't see.
- ensure the function is correcly hooked on the checkbox (you may have a problem of not fully loaded DOM, depending on your page)

Comment: Yes, it works on JSFiddle, but it doesn't work when I copy the code into a file and put it on my website. I have no idea what JSFiddle is doing so can't really see where to start on that.

Comment: Did you put the js code in an onload function at the end of the body ? See edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

I was using the same name for two elements: both the checkbox input and the text box input (in the innerHtml were called "extrabed". Changing one of those has fixed it.

Thanks to all of you who offered help.